# How do I set a max allowed volume limit?

Tags: volume-control, volume

On iPhone I could set a maximum volume limit so I wouldnt be able to put my music too loud accidentally. How do I do this in Android? I dont seem to find the setting in the volume menu.

Comment: "*navigate to System -> etc -> mixer_paths.xml. Open the file in the text editor, then locate the text <path name="headphones">. By default, the headphone volume level is set to max out at "84." Edit these values to whatever you want*" as per http://oneplus.wonderhowto.com See if that's true for your device as well. Also, which Android device and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the headphone output rather than the speaker, then you could use an app such as "Headset Button Controller" [Link to Play Store Trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headset).

I have the paid version on my phone, and I like it a lot.  It allows you to set up button controls for various apps, but it also has a nice feature that allows you to set the default volume when you plug in the headset.  You can set the minimum and maximum, also, but this would only work with a headset like the iphone's, with volume control that controls the phone.