# how do I set the max allowed volume on Android?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, volume-control

On iOS, it is possible to set the max volume limit so I don't get deaf. I know Android has the warning but I much prefer to set the limit.

I did checked the settings on the Xperia and nothing stands out.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a max allowed volume limit?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/78077)

Comment: but that was 2014. Android (or AOSP) has changed since then? :)

Comment: You can probably use some volume control like Viper Audio.
Or afaik (not someone who uses tasker, so not sure) this can also be accomplished with tasker (detect certain level of volume using tasker and if it goes above that level, reduce it back).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I boost the volume on my Droid's speaker?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/how-can-i-boost-the-volume-on-my-droids-speaker)

Comment: to lucky: the discussion you linked is dated 2010. A lot of things has changed since then on Android